# How to push your updated changes to an ec2 instance with django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework

I have followed the tutorial below and successfully deployed my django app to AWS on ec2.

my configuration is `Ubuntu`,`nginx`, `gunicorn` and `supervisor`

```
https://dev.to/subhamuralikrishna/deploying-django-application-to-aws-ec2-instance-2a81
```

(**I have not connected my EC2 to RDS yet**)

Now that I have made some changes to my django app and pushed the changes to `github`, How do I update the changes to my `Ec2 instance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ssh into your EC2 instance and run `git pull` so that your working tree in your EC2 is up-to-date with what's on github.

Then, you need to restart your server so that your changes are reflected on the server. For EC2 instances that are served using apache, this can be done by running `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: i see i am new to deployment on `aws`, thanks it gives me an idea. I am using `nginx`, `gunicorn`. `ubuntu` and `supervisor`

Comment: I apologize, I mistyped... if you are using `apache` then you should run `sudo service apache2 restart`. In your case, with nginx, you should run `sudo systemctl restart nginx` after your git pull

Comment: thanks for giving  me the idea on how to proceed, after pulling from `github`...it was actually `sudo supervisorctl reload` then `sudo service restart nginx`